# What is the fastest way to get all the titles of emails in a folder?

Tags: performance-tuning, email

I am using the function `MailSearch[]` to get the titles of all the relevant emails in one of my folders in Gmail. What I am currently doing works, but it takes a few seconds, and those seconds really count for what I am doing. Here is the current code:

```
alerts = 
  Normal[MailSearch[
     connection["Personal/alerts"], <|
      "From" -> "support@xyz.com"|>][[All, "Subject"]]];
actionTitles = 
 Flatten[DeleteCases[
   StringCases[
    alerts, {"Covered " ~~ __, "Covered " ~~ __, "Shorted " ~~ __, 
     "Bought " ~~ __, "Sold " ~~ __}], {}]]
```

Which returns a list like the following:

```
{"Covered GLBS", "Covered HTBX", "Shorted HTBX", "Shorted HTBX", \
"Covered HTBX", "Bought KGKG", "Sold KGKG", "Bought TBLT", "Sold \
TBLT", "Bought KGKG", "Sold KGKG", "Bought TAIT", "Sold TAIT", \
"Bought KBLB", "Sold KBLB", "Bought HMPQ", "Sold HMPQ", "Bought \
KBLB", "Sold KBLB"}
```

The `MailSearch[]` part of the code is slightly redundant, as all of the mail in the folder Personal/alerts" has already been filtered to be only from the fictitious support@xyz.com. However, I have found this is a lot faster than just using:

```
connection["Personal/alerts"][All]
```

Is there an quicker way that I'm not aware of with which I can just get all the `Subject` entities from the emails in that particular folder? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked which part is slow? I would suspect that the call to `MailSearch` is slow, while the second part most probably is pretty fast, but that depends on how many entries you have in `alerts` and it is always better to check. It will not help a lot but I think the `DeleteCases` in the second part is superfluos because the `Flatten` will remove the empty lists anyway and I think is more efficient in doing so...

Comment: @AlbertRetey - Thanks! I hadn't thought of that. And yes, it's definitely the MailSearch function that is causing the most slowdown - I got it working a lot faster, just by using a much smaller inbox. I think maybe the volume of the entire inbox might slow things down, so using a newer email address seemed to help. Something else that would really help would be some sort of functionality that let me just get the text titles of the emails in a specific folder, and then search those by text.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with the `MailSearch` function, but from its documentation I don't think you can just get the subjects. It might be possible to directly search the subject lines on the server though, which is - if possible - what I think would be the most efficient way to perform the task. Maybe you can change the question (or create a new one) giving a more detailed scope...

Comment: @AlbertRetey - Thanks, I appreciate it, that's a good idea. I did end up just doing most of the work on the server side, which seems to work a lot faster.